# Expand range to an undefined range

Tags: excel, vba

I have a large number of xml files in one folder.

The below code, looks for specific xml files by searching a field in the XML file and comparing it to a range in the Excel sheet.

It then copies the matching xml files to a new folder and renames them for readability.

Everything is working, except very slow.

It looks at a very small range. I would like to extend the range to a pivot table with values from F4 and down, if there is data in the cells.

```
Global so1, so2, so3, so4, so5, so6, so7, so8, so9, so10, so11, so12, so13, so14, so15, so16, so17, so18 As String
Global Myfile As String
Global WholeOrderNumber As String
Global NewFile As String
Global Myfiletemp As String
Global FileName As String
Global TempFolder As String
Global OrderNumber As String
Global TempOrdernumber As String
Global TempMonth As String
Global Month As String

Sub Find_Delivery_XML()
'******************************************************************
'loop trough folder
'and locate ordre numbers in XML Files in range "C4" to "C21"
'if found then call loadXML and copyit to copy the files
'******************************************************************
 Application.EnableEvents = True
 Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic
 Application.ScreenUpdating = True

Worksheets("Main").Select ' pick Main sheet
so1 = Range("C4")
so2 = Range("C5")
so3 = Range("C6")
so4 = Range("C7")
so5 = Range("C8")
so6 = Range("C9")
so7 = Range("C10")
so8 = Range("C11")
so9 = Range("C12")
so10 = Range("C13")
so11 = Range("C14")
so12 = Range("C15")
so13 = Range("C16")
so14 = Range("C17")
so15 = Range("C18")
so16 = Range("C19")
so17 = Range("C20")
so18 = Range("C21")

'In Case of Cancel
NextCode:

  TempFolder = "C:\xml_found\"
  myPath = "C:\xml_all\"
  myExtension = "DK2W_PJ_SO_*.xml*"
  Myfile = Dir(myPath & myExtension)

'Loop through each file in folder
  Do While Myfile <> ""
  Myfiletemp = "C:\xml_all\" & Myfile

loadXML

If s18 = OrderNumber Then
  copyit
End If
If so17 = OrderNumber Then
  copyit
End If
If so16 = OrderNumber Then
  copyit
End If
If so15 = OrderNumber Then
  copyit
End If
If so14 = OrderNumber Then
  copyit
End If
If so13 = OrderNumber Then
  copyit
End If
If so12 = OrderNumber Then
  copyit
End If
If so11 = OrderNumber Then
  copyit
End If
If so10 = OrderNumber Then
  copyit
End If
If so9 = OrderNumber Then
  copyit
End If
If so8 = OrderNumber Then
  copyit
End If
If so7 = OrderNumber Then
  copyit
End If
If so6 = OrderNumber Then
  copyit
End If
If so5 = OrderNumber Then
  copyit
End If
  If so4 = OrderNumber Then
copyit
End If
If so3 = OrderNumber Then
  copyit
End If
If so2 = OrderNumber Then
  copyit
End If
If so1 = OrderNumber Then
  copyit
End If

DoEvents

Myfile = Dir

  Loop

  MsgBox "Done"

ResetSettings:
  'Reset Macro Optimization Settings
    Application.EnableEvents = True
    Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub


Sub loadXML()
'******************************************************************
'load XML files and get ordernumber from XML files
' located in = xobject.ChildNodes.Item(1).Text
'******************************************************************

Dim strPath As String
Dim XDoc As Object
Set XDoc = CreateObject("MSXML2.DOMDocument")
XDoc.async = False
XDoc.validateOnParse = False
XDoc.Load (Myfiletemp)
Set xObjDetails = XDoc.ChildNodes(0)
Set xobject = xObjDetails.FirstChild
TempOrdernumber = xobject.ChildNodes.Item(1).Text
TempMonth = xobject.ChildNodes.Item(2).Text
OrderNumber = Mid(TempOrdernumber, 8, 7)
WholeOrderNumber = TempOrdernumber
Month = Mid(TempMonth, 4, 2)
NewFile = WholeOrderNumber & "_" & Mid(Myfiletemp, 24, 27)

End Sub


Sub copyit()
'******************************************************************
'copy files to DIR "C2" and rename them to the new filename "NewFile"
'NewFile = WholeOrderNumber + "_" + last 27 characters of Myfiletemp
'******************************************************************
    Dim oFSO As Object
    Set oFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
    Call oFSO.CopyFile(Myfiletemp, TempFolder & Range("C2") & "\" & NewFile, True)

End Sub
```

Comment: `If Not IsError(Application.Match(OrderNumber, Range("C:C"), 0)) Then` will tell you if the order number is found in column C.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe this will work, i just put the repeating parts of your code into loops...

```
Global so() As String
Global Myfile As String
Global WholeOrderNumber As String
Global NewFile As String
Global Myfiletemp As String
Global FileName As String
Global TempFolder As String
Global OrderNumber As String
Global TempOrdernumber As String
Global TempMonth As String
Global Month As String

    Sub Find_Delivery_XML()
Dim lastRow As long
Dim firstRow As long
Dim i as long
Dim col as long
'******************************************************************
'loop trough folder
'and locate ordre numbers in XML Files in column C
'if found then call loadXML and copyit to copy the files
'******************************************************************
 Application.EnableEvents = True
 Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic
 Application.ScreenUpdating = True

Worksheets("Main").Select ' pick Main sheet

firstRow = 4 '<----first row of data here, i put it to 4 because in your example it starts at C4
i = firstRow
col = 6 'Set Column Number here. Since F is number 6 in the Alphabet thats the default i set it to now
With Application.Worksheets("Main")
    Do Until .Cells(i, col) = "" and i > firstRow
        i = i + 1
    Loop
    lastRow = i - 1
    ReDim so(lastRow)

    For i = firstRow To lastRow
        so(i) = .Cells(i, col)
    Next i
End With


'In Case of Cancel
NextCode:

  TempFolder = "C:\xml_found\"
  myPath = "C:\xml_all\"
  myExtension = "DK2W_PJ_SO_*.xml*"
  Myfile = Dir(myPath & myExtension)

'Loop through each file in folder
  Do While Myfile <> ""
  Myfiletemp = "C:\xml_all\" & Myfile

loadXML


For i = firstRow To lastRow
    If so(i) = OrderNumber Then
      copyit
    End If
Next i


DoEvents

Myfile = Dir

  Loop

  MsgBox "Done"

ResetSettings:
  'Reset Macro Optimization Settings
    Application.EnableEvents = True
    Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub

Sub loadXML()
'******************************************************************
'load XML files and get ordernumber from XML files
' located in = xobject.ChildNodes.Item(1).Text
'******************************************************************

Dim strPath As String
Dim XDoc As Object
Set XDoc = CreateObject("MSXML2.DOMDocument")
XDoc.async = False
XDoc.validateOnParse = False
XDoc.Load (Myfiletemp)
Set xObjDetails = XDoc.ChildNodes(0)
Set xobject = xObjDetails.FirstChild
TempOrdernumber = xobject.ChildNodes.Item(1).Text
TempMonth = xobject.ChildNodes.Item(2).Text
OrderNumber = Mid(TempOrdernumber, 8, 7)
WholeOrderNumber = TempOrdernumber
Month = Mid(TempMonth, 4, 2)
NewFile = WholeOrderNumber & "_" & Mid(Myfiletemp, 24, 27)



End Sub

Sub copyit()
'******************************************************************
'copy files to DIR "C2" and rename them to the new filename "NewFile"
'NewFile = WholeOrderNumber + "_" + last 27 characters of Myfiletemp
'******************************************************************
    Dim oFSO As Object
    Set oFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
    Call oFSO.CopyFile(Myfiletemp, TempFolder & Range("C2") & "\" & NewFile, True)

End Sub
```

Comment: Unfortunately it does not work. It reacts as if no data is in the range. I also tried with a hardcoded string.

Comment: Where exactly is your data?

Comment: Its a Pivot table with Values from F4 and down.

Comment: Ok then obviously it didn't work. I assumed it was in Column C since that was the example you provided. I updated it to use Data from column F. I commented the line in the Code you have to look at for the input column.

Comment: Also note that the code stops once it hits an empty cell moving down from F4, so if you have gaps in your data you'd  have to adapt the code aswell.

Comment: Thanks GWD, I should have clarified I already made that correction myself.

Comment: If my answer helped you to solve your problem feel free to mark it as correct!

Comment: Sorry, the code does not work. I made the correction for F4 myself. Before my first comment. I do appreciate your help though. :)

Comment: I updated it  12 hours ago so it does work... Also it was not wrong in the first place, you just didn't phrase the question correctly. Or do you mean you didn't use my code at all?

Comment: It works, I'm an idiot. I forgot an ending "\" in one of the paths.